# How to clean up .table and .gnuplot using latexmk

Tags: compiling, latexmk, build-system, cleanup

I'm using `latexmk` as my building assistance. I'm also trying to use it as the clean-up contractor... In `.latexmkrc` I added:

```perl
$pdf_previewer = "open -a /Applications/Skim.app"; 
$clean_ext = "rel paux lox pdfsync out bbl %R.run.xml %R.table %R.gnuplot";
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -8bit -etex -shell-escape -file-line-error -halt-on-error -synctex=1 %O %S';
$new_viewer_always [0];
$pvc_view_file_via_temporary [1];
```

so it will remove the `tex_name.func_name.table` and `tex_name.func.gnuplot` file types in addition to the defaults. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I run `latexmk -c`, this is the first output's line (I don't know if it is related):

```
Useless use of array element in void context at (eval 12) line 5, <GEN0> chunk 1.
```

And these files stay in the directory. How can I make them gone?

### Edit:

As @N.N. suggested I corrected the mistake in the last two code lines. As for the main issue of this question, I have to clarify the case. Compiling my document produces several files all having the following filename pattern: `tex_main_name.function_name.gnuplot` and similarly `tex_main_name.function_name.table`. I want `latexmk -c` to remove *all* of them. Therefore, using `func_name.table` in the `latexmkrc` will only remove two files. I hope the problem is clearer now.

### Edit 2:

As @N.N. asked, here's a WME:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Function
  \begin{scope}[domain=0.9:5.5,samples=200]
    \draw[<->,color=blue,line width=2pt] plot[id=func1]
    function{(x*x+x+1)/(x*x)} node[right] {$f(x)$};
  \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[domain=0.9:5.5,samples=200]
   \draw[<->,color=blue,line width=2pt] plot[id=func2]
   function{-(x*x+x+1)/(x*x)} node[right] {$f(x)$};
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this code generates two files, namely `file_name.func1.table` and `file_name.func2.gnuplot`. I want that `latexmk -c` will remove these two files.

Comment: The error message indicates that there was an error in the Perl code in your .latexmkrc file.  There should be some lines of context which may help to localize the error.  It would be useful if you added this to the quote of the error message.  More importantly, you should post the whole of your .latexmkrc file.  The error is almost certainly somewhere other than the line from .latexmkrc you posted; that line is error free.

Comment: @JohnCollins: Thanks for your comment. I didn't want to pollute the question. Now, I added all the complete `.latexmkrc`. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dror Could you please provide a full test case, i.e. a minimal TeX file that produces the .gnuplot and .table files that you want cleaned up.

Comment: @Dror For me your example generates `test.func1.table` and `test.func1.gnuplot` (i.e. func1 and not func2). Anyway I have updated my answer to cover it.

Comment: @Dror: Have you solved the problem? - I would like to use the solution. What you want is not `$clean_ext = "%R.table %R.gnuplot";` but `$clean_ext = "%R.*.table %R.*.gnuplot";` - but the wildcard `*` does not work:o(

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: As far as I recall, I didn't manage to solve the issue. Otherwise, I'd mark an answer as accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not an answer, but an email from John Collins, saying that it will be possible in the future.**

> Good idea.
>
> Unfortunately, it somewhat conflicts with another request, which is to
>   allow the patterns in $clean_ext to be regular expressions (regexps). 
>   The wildcard idea is easier to implement, but the regexp idea gives
>   finer control over the files to be deleted, which is needed in some
>   situations.
>
> In any case, the suggestion of allowing wildcards or regexps in the
>   patterns is on my list of future enhancements.
>
> John
>
> Hans-Peter E. Kristiansen wrote: Tank you for a wonderful tool -
>   latekmk. Can I suggest an improvement: In line 7016 add "glob" to the
>   unlink  command, to make it possible to use wildcards in the rc file
>   like this: $clean_ext .= '%R.*.gnuplot';

Comment: Please update this once it gets updated.

Comment: @N.N.: I am not 100% sure, what you mean? - is it to say that I should delete this post, once the real answer is possible and posted?

Comment: No no, I just meant that it would nice if you updated your answer once the feature is implemented to reflect that.

Comment: @N.N.: I will try to answer the question, when a solution is possible, but I do not know when - and I have no advantage over others to know.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Is there some update regarding this issue?

Comment: @Dror: No news. The latest version of latexmk is still not able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You have not used the correct syntax for the last two lines in your .latexmkrc. What you seem to have done is to have copied the last two lines in your .latexmkrc from the latexmk manual in which the variables are listed along with their default value in square brackets. The correct syntax is roughly as follows (see the manual for details):

```perl
$variable_name = value;
```

So the last two lines of your .latexmkrc should read:

```perl
$new_viewer_always = 0;
$pvc_view_file_via_temporary = 1;
```

Also you have no specified the files to clean out correctly. The manual reads:

> It is also possible to specify a more general pattern of file to be 
>   deleted, by using the place holder %R, as in commands.  Thus setting
>
> ```perl
> $clean_ext = "out %R-blx.bib";
> ```
>
> in an initialization file will imply that when a clean-up operation 
>   is  specified,  not  only  is  the  standard  set of files deleted,
>   but also files of the  form  FOO.out  and  FOO-blx.bib, where  FOO 
>   stands  for the basename of the file being processed (as in FOO.tex).

So if you have a file named test.tex and which when it is compiled generates `test.func1.gnuplot` and `test.func1.table` and you want latexmkrc to clean out these, then you should add `func1.table` and `func1.gnuplot` to the variable `$clean_ext`. In some of my tests of other plots also `test.pgf-plot.gnuplot` and `test.pgf-plot.table` were generated. Thus, to cover all cases you should set the variable as follows:

```perl
$clean_ext = "func1.gnuplot func1.table pgf-plot.gnuplot pgf-plot.table";
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The new version indeed doesn't produce error message, but still `latexmk -c` it won't remove the `*.*.table` and `*.*.gnuplot`.

Comment: How can I handle the case where `test.func1.*` and `test.func2.*` etc. were generated?

Comment: @Dror Have you got an actual case where `test.func2.*` is generated? I tried to use wild cards, such as `*`, in `$clean_ext` but it seem that they are not supported nor documented so the only solution to do this with `$clean_ext` seems to be adding a phrase for each. Thus, if only a small number of `test.funcn.*` is generated you can add a phrase corresponding to each `n` to `$clean_ext`.

Comment: I do get more then one pair of the form above. Add another plot and have something different then `id=func1`. See my edit to the TeX example. Anyway, in this case, I guess this is the end. Thanks